# questions about Python regex

Tags: python, regex

Why the following pattern string results in a match of "A cat", instead of "a hat" since match is greedy by default?

```
>>> m = re.match(r'(\w+) (\w+)', "A cat jumpped over a hat")
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='A cat'>
```

Could someone shed some light on them?

Comment: The first group matches `A`, the space matches a space, the second group matches `cat` - why in the world would it look any further?  'Greediness' affects the possible length of a match, not where it starts - a non-greedy version of your regex would match `A c`.

Comment: In Regex, `\w` matches any "word" character (letter, digit, or underscore). Effectively, your regex is saying "look for cases where a word of at least one character exists followed by a space, and then another word of at least one character". You aren't making any specific restrictions in your regex.

Comment: Got it. perhaps it should be described as: match() is greedy but stop at first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official Python documentation on regexes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

> `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded, `re.match` starts from the beginning of the string-to-match and only checks for what is necessary. Notice `match='A cat'` at the end of the object's string representation denotes what was matched: `r'(\w+) (\w+)'` of `"A cat jumpped over a hat"`.

If you were to add a `$` to the end of your pattern, indicating the string-to-match should end there, it will not result in a match. And if you were to take that same pattern and shorten it to only two words, it would match once again:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\w+) (\w+)', "A cat jumpped over a hat")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='A cat'>
>>> re.match(r'(\w+) (\w+)$', "A cat jumpped over a hat")
>>> re.match(r'(\w+) (\w+)$', "A cat")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='A cat'>
```